# Creating Azure Dev Ops Pipeline to integrate with Terraform Cloud (CLI Version)

Tags: azure-devops, terraform

GitHub has a predefined action workflow to allow me to integrate a repository with Terraform Cloud (using the CLI integration, not the VCS integration). This is a useful feature that allows me to use Terraform Cloud as a remote backend, but still use the more versatile CLI driven syntax in my pipeline. The GitHub tool I am referring to can be seen here:

https://github.com/hashicorp/setup-terraform

Is there an equivalent functionality for Azure Dev Ops? Looking through the documentation, I have found examples of individuals linking Azure Dev Ops to terraform using the VCS setting, but that is not what I am looking for. Every other app/integration seems to assume a cloud storage account is being used for the backend - which is not the case. Struggling to understand 'if' I am able to integrate Azure Dev Ops with Terraform Cloud (remote backend) using the same CLI commands that GitHub has support for. Any thoughts?

EDIT : I found one 'possible' solution using a 3rd party integration available in the Azure Dev Ops store. A description of this implementation can be found here:
https://blog.devgenius.io/how-to-configure-azure-devops-with-terraform-enterprise-cac1bbd9810b

The app that is being used to achieve the connection is found here:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=charleszipp.azure-pipelines-tasks-terraform

This all looks like something of a hack, though - and I cannot find any official documentation supporting the implementation. I would still love to hear if there is a more 'above board' way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that there is no built-in task in Azure DevOps Pipeline can run Terraform using CLI integration.

As you said, we need to install a third-party extension to get the Terraform CLI task to meet the requirements.

In addition to the extension you mentioned in the question: [Azure Pipelines Terraform Tasks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=charleszipp.azure-pipelines-tasks-terraform) , you can also consider using this extension: [Terraforming](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArkiaConsulting.terraform-extension).

For example:

```
steps:
- task: terraformdownload@0
  displayName: 'Use Terraform latest'

- task: terraforminit@0
  displayName: 'Init Terraform'
  inputs:
    cwd: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)'

- task: terraformplan@0
  displayName: 'Terraform Plan'
  inputs:
    cwd: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)'
    tfrootpath: test

- task: terraformapply@0
  displayName: 'Terraform Apply'
  inputs:
    cwd: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)'
```

They are similar to the workflow in github action.